# how to change the category block right to left in magento?

Tags: magento

i use the magento 1.9 and install the MA2 theme.
how to category block change right to left column?
plz check this image below=" http://postimg.org/image/jcs8mssct/"

Comment: Can you post some layout codes of this theme, especially catalog_category_* sections? Seems to have a page/2columns-right.phtml template instead of page/2columns-left.phtml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the category layout via the backend :
catalog > Manage categories > select your category > Custom design tab > page layout  and change it to 2columns with left bar, but I don't think this will work with your template, it will change the page layout but it will not show the category list, it may show Magento layer nav if your category is anchor

or you can use your local.xml to add this :

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="right">
        <remove name="category.list"/>
    </reference>

    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="category.list" before="-" template="catalog/navigation/category_list.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

On MA2 template you can use the same code above on ma2\default\layout\local.xml